# How to change Map<String,String> to Map<String, List<String>> using a Java stream to split map values?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I have a `Map<String,String>` and I want to convert it to `Map<String, List<String>>`. It can be easily done with a for loop like below. But can I do the same thing using `stream()` in Java 8?

Sample `Map<String,String>`: `{"Country":"US,Japan","Food":"Burger,Cake"}`

Code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> newMap = null;
    for (String tmp: sampleMap.keySet()){
    newMap.putIfAbsent(tmp, sampleMap.get(tmp).split(","));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", "value1,value2");
        map.put("key2", "value3,value4,value5");
        map.put("key3", "value6");

        Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue().split(","))
                ));

        System.out.println(result); //-> Test the Output
    }
}
```